# Using David J Bradshaw's iframe-resizer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe, iframe-resizer

I have a Teamspeak status viewing script hosted on a different domain than my wordpress. So I'm trying to show the script results in a text/html widget using an iframe except it will not auto-size the height. Wordpress is on shared hosting so this script will not communicate with my teamspeak server from there. I cannot find any other ts3 viewers that work while auto-hide empty channels and not completely ugly. After doing some research I came across what appears to be the latest and greatest solution, [David J Bradshaw's iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer). Now I'm no expert on the subject and don't completely understand how I should set this up properly.

Currently my wordpress widget reads like this:

```
<iframe src="http://66.172.12.238/ts3.php" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

ts3.php reads like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TSStatus</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ts3/tsstatus.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ts3/tsstatus.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
require_once("/var/www/ts3/tsstatus.php");
$tsstatus = new TSStatus("ts3.greatarchitect.us", 10011);
$tsstatus->useServerPort(9987);
$tsstatus->imagePath = "/ts3/img/";
$tsstatus->timeout = 2;
$tsstatus->hideEmptyChannels = true;
$tsstatus->hideParentChannels = true;
$tsstatus->showNicknameBox = false;
$tsstatus->showPasswordBox = false;
echo $tsstatus->render();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and that's pretty much all I have right now. I was hoping someone could help me properly install/setup this iframe-resizer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a js file to your `http://66.172.12.238/ts3.php`

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d5xwK/embedded/result/) of your page and the example of the plugin page.

You need to add this js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://davidjbradshaw.com/iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

I dont know if you have any knowledge on how to load extra js files to Wordpress. If not, read here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

**Adding js files to Wordpress**

I would add this to a js file on it's own to execute the resizer, I'll name it iframe.js:

```
iFrameResize({
    log                     : true,                  // Enable console logging
    enablePublicMethods     : true,                  // Enable methods within iframe hosted page
});
```

Add this to your functions.php file of your theme:

```
    function theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/iframeResizer.min.js ', array(), '1.0.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/iframe.js ', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Make sure you add the iframeResizer.min.js and iframe.js in your `themefolder/js/` folder.

You can edit the iframe.js script as you dont need the extra options for the plugin!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to completely follow you. I added the following to my ts3.php.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/ts3/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>`
I'm not sure what else I'm suppose to do.

Comment: First get it to work on the Fiddle and then you can load it on Wordpress. I don't see the js file on http://66.172.12.238/ts3.php

Comment: Thanks, I finally got that working on fiddle. What has to be loaded on my wordpress? I was under the impression the iframe in the html widget would be it.

Comment: I dont think it's possible to resize the content on the iframe source remotely, this has security issues.. The other js file is to obviously communicate and resize the content accordingly. Please see my updated answer for adding the js files to your wordpress theme @JoshLs

Comment: Thanks. I done what you said. Created the iframe.js and upload it and iframeResizer.min.js to my themes /js folder. Then added your code to my theme's functions.php. I've got `<iframe src="http://66.172.12.238/ts3.php" width="100%" scrolling="no"></iframe>` added in my text/html widget but it's still behaving the same and not auto-sizing. Am I missing something?

Comment: View page source to see if the js files are there. Open the error console to find any js errors. Or send me the link to your website and I'll check for you.

Comment: I did find `/js/iframeResizer.min.js` in the homepage source code. And looking at the console revealed this error. `Error: http://66.172.12.238/ts3/resizer/js/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one`
http://test.greatarchitect.us

Comment: I can't seem to find that error in console. I also cant find the iframe.js? Did you load the js to execute the iFrameResize()?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, was there something I was suppose to change or that I didn't do?

Comment: Ok, thanks for trying to help. I found an alternative by using a wordpress iframe shortcode plugin. Funny thing is even this plugin said I would run into the same issue if I used `iframe same_height_as="content"` but using `iframe same_height_as="document"` did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I was wrong, that didn't work either. If you have anymore suggestions I'm listening, but pretty lost right now..

Comment: I didn't. It was a plugin that appeared to work but I didn't notice that it was actually extending the widget a mile long. So I'm back to my previous question about losing js to execute iFrameResize? I've done everything you suggested but nothing more, am I missing something? @msbodetti

Comment: When I saw your site, the iframeResizer.min.js file was in the source.. but I couldn't find the iframe.js? @JoshLs

Comment: I uploaded it to the same folder as iframeResizer.min.js, was there something else I needed to do? @msbodetti

Comment: Maybe rename `wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/iframe.js ', array(), '1.0.0', true );` to `wp_enqueue_script( 'iframe-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/iframe.js ', array(), '1.0.0', true );` there's probably a name conflict

Comment: Ok, I have done exactly that. No change to the Teamspeak widget though. Do you see any changes?

Comment: Ok it's there! But the js files aren't in the theme folder. It's not loading http://test.greatarchitect.us/wp-content/themes/buddyboss/js/iframe.js?ver=1.0.0

Comment: Ok, I am using a child theme. So the files are located at http://test.greatarchitect.us/wp-content/themes/buddyboss-child/js I moved those to the real theme also and it does appear to be working now. This is amazing and saves me from buying a plugin to do it.. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: That's great to hear :) glad to have helped out